# Selenium IDE - Not capturing button link

Tags: ide, selenium

In Selenium IDE, the application has got image as button. The click event for that is not capturing. Is there any alternative Selenium Commands available for that or otherwise, is there any JavaScript user extensions can be added?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your markup and then I could probably help you.. so you jsut want to record a click event in our brwoser on an image acting as a button right..

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. the image will act as a button..

Found a solution for that!!

Simply added a JavaScript code which supports clickAt() commands.

Comment: Keerthana,
I have a similar situations Selenium IDE doesn't recognize the img logon button
Can you please share your solution.
Best Regards
Sen

Answer (score 0):

To detect button as image you can use one of the below solution

```
xpath=//img[@src='/images/logo_home.png']
xpath=//img[@alt='Home']
//img[@src='/images/logo_home.png']
```